# How to convert a String ^ containing non-english characters to std::string

Tags: .net, string, winforms, c++-cli, clr

I'm writing a winforms apllication, and at one point I need to take text from a textbox and convert it into std::String. However, the textbox input can contain Lithuanian letters.
for conversion I use this code:

```
        std::string stringConvert(System::String ^ x) {
        msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
        return context.marshal_as<std::string>(x);
    }
```

however if the textbox has a word like "Žibutė", the result is "?ibut?". How can I fix this?

For example I set up a form with one textbox and one button. If I write something like this:

```
std::string a;

    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            a = stringConvert(textBox1->Text);
            setlocale(LC_ALL, "Lithuanian");
            std::cout << a << std::endl;
        }
```

and I input "ąčę", the console output is "???"

Comment: This is not C++. It is C++/CLI. Anyway, `std::string` is just a sequence of `char`s with no encoding. How do you determine what the result is? It's probably in the way you're printing it. Present a [MCVE].

Comment: added an example. If you need any more info, ask. @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: You should read the page I linked you to.

Comment: What *should* `ąčę` convert to? Those letters do not exist in the [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) character set, or in [ISO/IEC 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). Is there any reason that you're trying to use narrow characters (`std::string`) instead of wide characters (`std::wstring`)? Is there any reason you're using either of those instead of the very capable `String^`?

Comment: Windows consoles are notoriously awful about non-1252 characters. But you could convert them to UTF-8 (just use `Encoding::UTF8->GetBytes()` and pin the resulting array to build your `std::string`) and write them into a file or pass them to whatever `char`-based function you need to call.